# 任意ユーザが投稿したzipファイルを安全にダウンロードするには？

Tags: security

任意ユーザが投稿した(任意のプログラム系の)zipファイルを、PHPで安全にダウンロードする仕組みを作りたいのですが、注意すべきことは何ですか？
HTML出力の場合は「特殊文字を HTML エンティティに変換」しますが、ダウンロードの場合に該当する処理はありますか？
例えば、zipファイル形式ではなく、個別ファイルでexe形式以外の拡張子のみokとすれば安全ですか？

Comment: どういう意味で「安全」とおっしゃってるのか気になりました。アップロードされたものとダウンロードされたものの同一性を担保したいのでしょうか（たとえば、中間者攻撃されていないことを保証したいなど）。exe形式ファイルを気にされてるようですが、それはダウンロード自体じゃなくてダウンロードした後に実行するかどうかの話になりそうです。

Comment: 質問文の最後「exe形式以外の拡張子のみOKとすれば…」はアップロードを受け付けるファイル形式をどうするかについて言及しているようにも見えます。「プログラム系のZIPファイル」も何を指しているのかが分かりません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

サーバーにアンチウイルスソフトをインストールしてアップロードしたコンテンツに対して実行する方法があります。
定義ファイルも更新が必要になりますし、面倒なので、どうしても必要性がない限りはこういう機能は作らない方がいいです。

Linux用のオープンソースのアンチウイルスソフト
http://www.clamav.net/

単純にダウンロードの実装をしたいなら、以下のようにヘッダーを指定してください。

```
$filename = 'download.zip';
$filepath = '/home/user/file.zip';
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filepath));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
readfile($filepath);
```

Comment: 「Clam AntiVirus」を初めて知りました。オープンソースかつ直近でも更新継続されているようなのでとても魅力的に思えたのですが。「どうしても必要性がない限りはこういう機能は作らない方がいいです」この件についてもう少し知りたいです。面倒というのは、定義ファイル更新以外にも何かあるのでしょうか？

Comment: suzukisさんがおっしゃるように最終的にはダウンロードユーザー責任ですね。

Comment: ー般的に信用のおけるサービス上で実装するには、アップロードできるユーザーを限るなどの必要性はあるかと思います。例えば宅ふぁいる便のようなサービスではダウンロードする側が、アップロードしたユーザーを信用できるゆえに成り立っています。ウイルス実行ファイルをzip化されたら、suzukisさんがおっしゃる通り、ほぼ検出されないでしょう。

Answer (score 3):

ユーザーがファイルをアップロード可能な場合、サービスに応じた特定の形式のコンテンツのみを受け入れるようにすべきです。任意のファイルまたはアーカイブをアップロード/ダウンロード可能にすべきではありません。任意のファイルをアップロード/ダウンロード可能なサービスは、リスクを度外視するか、利用者がリスクを認識したうえでしか成立しません。

アンチウイルスソフトは気休め程度の対策にしかなりません。世間に出回っているマルウェア(と似ているもの)は排除できますが、例えば私がいま「特定のファイル(群)を消去する実行ファイル(を含んだzip)」を作ったとして、それはアンチウイルスソフトではたいてい検出できません。

エスケープというのは、「ある文脈において、その文脈を破壊するようなデータを文脈に適した形に変換する」ものです。危険なものを安全にするとか、危険なものを排除する仕組みではありません。HTMLであれば、エンドユーザー入力をもとの文脈を破壊しないようにエスケープすれば元の文脈以上に危険なことにはなりません。ところが任意のバイナリには「元の文脈」が存在しないので、エスケープのしようがありません。

Comment: 任意のファイル形式をアップロード可能なサービスの一つにGitHubがあると思うのですが、運営側はセキュリティ対策をどう行っていると考えられますか？　コード公開されているので、利用者がリスクを認識したうえで成立というスタンスですか？　これまで気にしたことはなかったのですが、GitHubの中にも実行するとウイルスとなるようなファイルはあり得る？？

Answer (score 1):

質問文に主語が無いので何が何だかわからないです。

```
任意ユーザーが投稿した zip ファイルを　　　ここまでは良い
PHP で安全にダウンロードする              誰がダウンロードするの？
```

サーバー管理者？　アップロードした当人？　リスクがあることを共有済みの会員？
全く無関係で知識も経験もない第三者？

例えばコンピュータウイルスのサンプルを保存しておきたい・共有したいなんてのは「ウイルス対策チーム」（＝先の例でいう当人、会員）ではありそうな話です。そういう専門家なら安全にダウンロードする手法というのは各人で共有できていそうですし、サーバー側で不要な対策ソフトを入れられてしまうと迷惑です。

逆に zip に危険がありうることを知らない一般人向けのサービスを想定しているならウイルス zip とか [zip bomb](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%AB%98%E5%9C%A7%E7%B8%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E7%88%86%E5%BC%BE) とかを（攻撃者がアップロードすることを禁ずるのは困難なので）一般人にダウンロードさせない・攻撃者を BAN する、ように対策する必要はありそうです。

「安全」っつか「セキュリティ」ってのは設計そのものなので、案件から分析しないと始まりません。

zip を「ダウンロード→保存」させれば「ダウンロード→自動で開く」よりは安全でしょう。（その後、操作員が展開＋実行させれば同じことですが）んで、一般的な Web UA (ブラウザのこと) は、リンクに `Content-Disposition: attachment` とあるとき添付ファイルを**自動的に開かず** ダウンロードしようとします、ってのが @nomlis の回答ですね。オイラも強く同意します（が、これだけでは終局的なセキュリティの担保にはなりえません）

Comment: ダウンロードも任意ユーザが行うのですが、対象は2段階に分かれていて、当初は「プログラムに興味を抱いている人」、以降は「全く無関係で知識も経験もない第三者」の予定です。「https://qiita.com/mpyw/items/695f443674aef8d349c3」に「スクリプトとして実行可能な *.php *.cgi *.rb *.py にマッチするファイル名のものは禁止する (トロイの木馬対策)」との記載があるのですが、例えば拡張子「php」ファイルでも、記述内容によっては安全ではない(危険となる)可能性はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: そのコメントって（およびほかの方へのコメントも）新しい質問ですよね。コメント欄にて続けず新規質問を挙げることをお勧めします。

Comment: @re9 「何を作ろうとしていて」「どんな仕様にするのか」をしっかり決めた上で(それらの情報も含めて)質問文を組み立てるべきなのかなと思います。単に「安全にファイルをダウンロード」では曖昧すぎます。